# Java способы проектирования приложений, архитектура или как правильно писать код

Tags: java, архитектура, чистый-код

Есть ли какие-то правила при проектировании различного рода приложений и где можно об этом почитать?
Со временем понял что при написании больших проектов, с каждым новом сеансом работы все труднее с читабельностью...То есть мозгу нужно все больше времени для "кеширования" информации которая отвечает на вопросы зачем это, а зачем то, что бы дальше продолжать допиливать...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходимо бороться со сложностью кода. Много полезной информации можно найти по ключевому слову SOLID (в частности по вашей проблеме - SRP). Так же с этим помогают широко известные и узнаваемые паттерны проектирования.

Разбивая код на простые блоки с одной задачей и очевидным интерфейсом, вы сильно ускоритесь из-за отсутствия необходимости детально копаться в имплементации каждого из них.

Answer (score 3):

Конечно есть. Самое простое, что приходит на ум - "Чистый код" Роберта Мартина.